# Any way to extend javascript's array.sort() method to accept another parameter?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects. I'd prefer not to write a custom sort method for each attribute.

Is there anyway I could extend the built-in `array.sort()` method to accept an extra parameter, describing the attribute to sort on? E.g.,

```
array.sort(function(a, b, attr) { return a.attr - b.attr; }, 'name');
```

Comment: Your example makes no sense, because you aren't actually using the `attr` parameter, you are simply getting the `attr` property of the objects. You probably want to change it to:
`array.sort(function(a, b, attr) { return a[attr] - b[attr]; }, 'name');`

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Write a function generator that accepts a property name:

```
function propComparator(prop) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return a[prop] - b[prop];
    }
}

arr.sort(propComparator('name'));
```

You can also save the sorters for later use, directly, or as parameters:

```
var compareNames = propComparator('name');
var compareFoos = propComparator('foo');
...
arr.sort(compareNames);
takesComparator(compareFoos);
```

---

> `sort` sorts in-place, which may or may not be desirable.

---

*(Updated for ES6, and so it actually works with different types.)*

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'John', age: 92 },
  { name: 'Dave', age: 42 },
  { name: 'Justin', age: 3 }
]

const propComparator = (propName) =>
  (a, b) => a[propName] == b[propName] ? 0 : a[propName] < b[propName] ? -1 : 1

arr.sort(propComparator('name'))
console.log("By name", arr)

arr.sort(propComparator('age'))
console.log("By age", arr)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave I was having trouble passing a variable to sort an array of objects and this worked perfectly!

Comment: See it here live. http://jsfiddle.net/mivaas19/AMukX/ .  Great answer; but Iam still wondering how it works.

Comment: @mivaas19 It works because you can pass function references around, whether immediate functions, like you see with jQuery event handlers a lot of the time, or named functions, where you just leave off the parentheses. It's a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 10):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function sortByProperty(array, propertyName) {
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a[propertyName] - b[propertyName];
    });
}

var sortedByName = sortByProperty(myArray, "name");
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a huge difference between the two versions; @DaveNewton, can you explain your comment? Also, thanks to both of you, both answers look like they'll work...

Comment: @danwoods The difference is one of communication: I prefer the more functional-/OOP-looking approach that keeps the array as the primary actor in the statement: `arr.sort(how)` to me is more communicative than `how(arr, moreHow)`. Also, the generated functions act on anything that has properties with the name, instead of wrapping up an array-specific, or `sort`-function-specific, entity.

Comment: One would give you a compare function (Daves), and the other uses an anonymous function. So if you want the compare function, use the one that gives it.

Answer (score 6):

Use prototypes to compare strings and numbers correctly

```
Array.prototype.sortAttr = function(attr,reverse) {
  var sorter = function(a,b) {
    var aa = a[attr];
    var bb = b[attr];
    if(aa+0==aa && bb+0==bb) return aa-bb; // numbers
    else return aa.localeCompare(bb); // strings
  }
  this.sort(function(a,b) {
    var result = sorter(a,b);
    if(reverse) result*= -1;
    return result;
  });
};
```

Example

```
var data = [
  {name: "Josh", age: 18},
  {name: "John", age: 17},
  {name: "Bob", age: 20},
  {name: 0, age: "error"}
];

data.sortAttr("name");
// data is now sorted by name
```

Comment: Prototypes or not isn't the issue with strings v. numbers, it's an issue of the sort function being provided.

Comment: The code sometimes throws "too much recursion" exception.
Modifying the sorter to use  localeCompare() instead of the custom defined compare is advised.

Comment: @d.popov What an archaeologist you are! 6 years ago localeCompare was buggy, perharps it is time to update now. Thanks for good catch, the recursion was horrible, I was so naive back then...

Answer (score 3):

**Is there anyway I could extend the built-in array.sort() method to accept an extra parameter**

all above answers are good . but i thought of adding some info about partial functions

for more info see bind in MDN and [partial Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions) or John Resig - [partial function](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/)

Example from MDN :

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]

//  Create a function with a preset leading argument
var leadingThirtysevenList = list.bind(undefined, 37);

var list2 = leadingThirtysevenList(); // [37]
var list3 = leadingThirtysevenList(1, 2, 3); // [37, 1, 2, 3]
```

here is an example from [Google Closure](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.source.html#line1119)

```
goog.partial = function(fn, var_args) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    // Prepend the bound arguments to the current arguments.
    var newArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    newArgs.unshift.apply(newArgs, args);
    return fn.apply(this, newArgs);
  };
};
```

to Use this function

```
    var fn=goog.partial(numberCompare,sortField,sortDirection);
    myarray.sort (fn);


    var numberCompare = function (sortField,sortDirection,value1,value2){
      // sort code goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone needs ascending order, here is DaveNewton's solution with a reverse option

```
const sorton = (prop, asc=0) => {
    if(!asc) return (a, b) => a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 1
    else return (b, a) => a[prop] == b[prop] ? 0 : a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 1
}
```

`arr.sort(propComparator('age', 1))`

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript it is simple. I had created a little different sorting function for string sorting. Since Array.sort takes a function, you can also pass closure. So my sorting function is:

```
sortCaseInsensitive(a,b,column:string) {
  return (a[column]? a[column] : '').toLowerCase().
  localeCompare((b[column]? b[column] : '').toLowerCase());
}
```

And if my data is like

```
    [ 
{ value:'a', label:'a1'}
    { value:'b', label:'b1'} 
]
```

Then, you can call:

```
arrayList123.sort((a,b)=>myself.sortCaseInsensitive(a,b,'value'));
```

There you can pass any arguments. Sweet and simple.

Answer (score -1):

### *Actually Extending It*

In order to actually extend `Array.prototype.sort`, we have a couple options:

- Mutate its *signature*
- Sort in multiplicity using *Decorators* | *Adapters* ( Parent Pattern: *Wrapper* )

I was in your same boat and decided to utilize the 2nd approach:

```
private sortAddresses = (a, b) => {
    let iPrimeFlag = this.sortAddressesByPrimaryFlag(a, b);
    let iAlphaNum = this.sortAddressesByAlphaNum(a, b);

    if (iPrimeFlag === 1) return 1;
    else return iAlphaNum;
};

private sortAddressesByPrimaryFlag(a, b) {
    if (b.primaryFlag > a.primaryFlag) return 1;
    if (b.primaryFlag < a.primaryFlag) return -1;
    return 0;
}

private sortAddressesByAlphaNum(a, b) {
    let aAddress = this.$.formatAddress(a);
    let bAddress = this.$.formatAddress(b);

    if (aAddress > bAddress) return 1;
    if (aAddress < bAddress) return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Intent

I'm already calling `this.addresses.sort(this.sortAddresses)` **in several places** and I'd like to keep my *ChangeCost* low -- especially, knowing that we may get requirements to sort on *even more heuristics*.

So, in order to follow *The Gang of Four's Two 'Rules of Thumb'* --

> Program to an interface, not an implementation.

and

> Encapsulate what varies.

-- I decided to keep my *signature* the same and wrap my original method.

It would be useful if we didn't have to go through and change each line where we invoke `this.addresses.sort`. Instead, we'd like to be able to add an *indefinite* number of sorting "heuristics" to the action of sorting.

The goal is to prioritize address objects whose `primaryFlag` is `'Y'` and then take the address string -- `'0000 Some St, #0000, City, ST 00000'` -- and sort these alphanumerically. Since `'Y'` is `>` `'N'`, we'd like to move it *up* in the list, visually, by lowering its index. Sorting the address string alphanumerically says that if `'Colorado'` is `>` `'Alabama'`, then we should bump `'Colorado'` *down* in the list visually by increasing its index.

#### Usage

This is used for sorting **Addresses** by different values. One value, `primaryFlag`, is to denote if its the [ only ] default address; in my case, `primaryFlag` **is a sting of `'Y'` or `'N'`, not a boolean** (ask my Back-End teammates why in the world?). The other value, `this.$.formatAddress(a|b)`, takes these address `[object Object]`'s -- `a` and `b` -- and invokes `formatAddress` off of my *Sandbox* `this.$`.

The line `if (iPrimeFlag === 1) return 1;` is saying, "anytime primaryFlag is 1, just bump that toward the head (beginning) of the array, otherwise, do whatever the alphanumeric heuristic decides", which allows us to *prioritize* by one heuristic while falling back on another.

Also note, `.bind(undefined, 'prop')` is **not** being used in my actual code as I don't need it; **this is just here for demonstrative purposes**.

Now, I know I'm that person who provided some *TypeScript* -- lemme know if you don't understand what's happening in this code :)

Cheers!

Comment: Isn’t this just a completely normal comparison function that isn’t generic as the question asked?

Comment: @Ryan, no isn't. I'm solving the Questioner's problem by *wrapping* methods instead of *binding* parameters. No thanks for down voting my answer just because you're hurt that you haven't solved your sorting issue.

Comment: No I’m pretty sure this is just a completely normal comparison function

Comment: Suit yourself. But I think you could be missing something important here.

Comment: It can't *not* be a normal sorting method--all "sort" can use is a normal sorting method; that it's choosing between the results of two other normal sorting methods doesn't change that. It also doesn't appear to address the original question unless your suggestion is to write a sort function for every possible property name?