# How to use Jquery UI plugins with Backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have a list of elements that I am controlling with Backbone.js, with a view for the list as well as a view for each `li` element, which each controls a model. I'd like to implement the sortable plugin from the jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/, and be able to update the value in models based on their position. Is there a way to do this from within the views, or do I need to take a different approach here?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using a collection to store these models, on the collection you have all the information required to get the 'order' of a model within the collection as long as your `comparator` function represents the sort order you need.

You can get the index of a particular model in a collection like this:

```
var idx = collectionInstance.indexOf(collectionInstance.get('itemId'))
```

I can't say I've used jQuery Sortable in conjunction with Backbone yet, as I've always felt that changing the comparator and applying sort does what I require of it.

I particularily liked the following implementation: [Proper way to sort a backbone.js collection on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865804/proper-way-to-sort-a-backbone-js-collection-on-the-fly).

From the Backbone Documentation we know that triggering a sort manually on a collection:

> Force a collection to re-sort itself. You don't need to call this
>   under normal circumstances, as a collection with a comparator function
>   will maintain itself in proper sort order at all times. Calling sort
>   triggers the collection's "reset" event, unless silenced by passing
>   {silent: true}