# How can i sort after i done the fetch in backone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

On click of the 'sort by age', i am calling a function to fetch data from server and sort by age value. i do this after i done the fetching, but it result nothing and return all..

any one give a correct way to implement this?

my code:

this code in the view class,

```
 sortByAge:function(){
        this.collection.fetch() //fetching new collection
        .done(function(data){ // once done i am passing data
            var filterType = data.sort('age') // correct way need to sort.
            that.collection.reset(filterType); // refreshing the collection
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If before doing a `fetch` you're already aware that you need `collection` to be sorted by some specific `column`, from the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch), we can pass `ajax` options to the `fetch`. So `fetch` might look like this:

```
this.collection.fetch({
  data: {
    sort_by: "age"
  }
});
```

`sort_by` parameter will be available in the `server` code being executed at the specified `url` for the collection, so you can return data from the server sorted by `sort_by` column. And then may be listen to `reset` event to do some work.

And if you want to sort `collection` after getting it on the client side may be you can look at these similar questions.

1. [Sorting a Backbone Collection After initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005411/sorting-a-backbone-collection-after-initialization)
2. [Proper way to sort a backbone.js collection on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865804/proper-way-to-sort-a-backbone-js-collection-on-the-fly)

Comment: This doesn't work without server-side implementation.  Keep looking.