# How can I modify this function to contain both ascendent and descendent functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to order descendent my table so I have this function for ascendant:

```
var compareUser = function (a, b) {
        if (a.username < b.username) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a.username > b.username) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

    };
```

How can I modify it to contain both descendent/ascendant function?

This is how I call the function:

```
      $(".theadUser").on('click', function () {
        userData.sort(compareUser);
        $('.theadUser').removeClass('headerUnSorted');
        $('.theadUser').addClass('headerAsc');
        console.log(userData);
        $("#users").html('');
        buildTable();
    });
```

I want when I click first on the button to order ascendant and when I click again order descendant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a function that can be used to create a "reverse" a comparison function:

```
function reverseCompare (fn) {
    return function (a, b) {
        // call original, reverse result
        return fn(a, b) * -1;
        // alternative as suggested by Alnitak, reverse arguments
        // return fn(b, a)
    }
}
```

In the basic form it can be used like so:

```
userData.sort(compareUser);                 // ascending/normal
userData.sort(reverseCompare(compareUser)); // descending/reversed
```

Applied to the code, it might go something like this:

```
var $t = $('.theadUser');
var sortedAsc = $t.hasClass('headerAsc');
if (!sortedAsc) {
   // not current sorted ascending, sort ascending
   userData.sort(compareUser);
   $t.removeClass('headerUnSorted headerDesc')
     .addClass('headerAsc');
} else {
   userData.sort(reverseCompare(compareUser));
   $t.removeClass('headerUnSorted headerAsc')
     .addClass('headerDesc');
}
```

Comment: perhaps an additional simple explanation between the two blocks, then?

Comment: You're welcome - also suggest `return fn(b, a)` instead of the `* -1`

Comment: How will look my functions ? should i keep mine and add this or should i modify mine like yours ? i`m noob so now i`m in confusion :)

Comment: @shaker Modify yours, and make sure you understand *why* you are doing so :) If the modification ends up very similar, that's fine.

Comment: seems that you are right ....:-? i have a table but with the fuction above its a little harderd to maake for all the fields asc /desc function :-? so now i`m stuck

Comment: i made it work for me but just for one column how can i make for all my column ( 4 ) but not repeting in most posibly way the code :-? can you help me ?

Comment: I recommend you look into learning libraries other than only jQuery. Its API for manipulating "models" and collections is not the strongest. Using something that understands more about the data will give you the "pretty" code you are looking for. What you want to do here is known as the "Strategy" design pattern. I recommend you look into `backbone.js`. It's tougher code to understand, but eventually you'll have to take the leap. here's a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865804/proper-way-to-sort-a-backbone-js-collection-on-the-fly