# Array Addition I JavaScript function on Coderbyte

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing a challenge on Coderbyte and I would be grateful for any advice on my question:

The challenge given to me:
"Using the JavaScript language, have the function ArrayAdditionI(arr) 
take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string true if 
any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the 
largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false. 
For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should 
return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will not be empty, 
will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers. "

The way I attempted to solve it: http://jsfiddle.net/reLsg0fg/

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr){
  var newArr=arr.sort(); // sorted from smallest to largest.
  var largestNum=newArr.slice(-1); // Gets the last number, which would be the largest.
  var loopArr=arr.sort().pop(); // Takes out the largest number for adding later.
  var result=0;

  for(var i=0; i<loopArr.length; i++){ // loops through all numbers.
    if(result/largestNum !== 1){ //when you divide a number by itself it will be 1.
        result+=loopArr[i]; // keep adding each number until get largest number.
    }else if(result === largestNum){
    return true;
    }
  } 
  return false;
}


// TESTS    
console.log("-----");   
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([4,6,23,10,1,3]));    
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([5,7,16,1,2]));   
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([3,5,-1,8,12]));
```

I'm supposed to get true, false, true. But I get false, false, false as if something is wrong within my loop. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reLsg0fg/

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you ^^

Comment: your sort is sorting strings, not numbers.

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript problem or do you just want us to solve the algorithm for you?

Comment: var max = Math.max.apply(0, arr);

Comment: Why do you do `result/largestNum !== 1` instead of `result !== largestNum`?

Comment: Your loop just adds the numbers in increasing order. It never tries combinations that skip some of the numbers.

Comment: @CodeiSir clearly I have a javaScript problem since I believe I solved the algorithm, except I may have misunderstood something in javaScript. I'm new.

Comment: @Barmar, you're right I didn't even notice that! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Nina Scholz Oh, I thought sort() worked for every character. Thank you for this. I will remember next time.

Comment: @Thank you CodeiSir for the Math.max() method.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it will help you as much as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to solve this problem with a for loop but I missed the fact that the challenge 
  is not asking that all numbers need to add up to equal the largest num, but it is also possible to
  add up to the largest num if we take some numbers out. Thus I decided to solve with recursion.

Tips:
    * The Math.max.apply() method takes an array and returns the largest number. Note that it usually works on strings as Math.max().
    * the sort() method can take a parameter to further expand it's purpose. Usually it only 
      sorts strings, but to sort numbers we include a function that finds which number is bigger.
    * First get the largest number.
    * Sort the array and remove the largest number to be used for recursion later.
    * Create a recursion function that checks if the numbers add up to the largest number, and if not, check that if some numbers in array are subtracted from the largest num they are equal to the largest number.

```
function ArrayAdditionI(array){
  var largestNum = Math.max.apply(0, array); // gets the largest number in array.
  array.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b;}).pop(); // sorts array and removes last(largest) number.

  function recursionCheck(arr, sum){
  // the base case when array empty.
    if(arr.length === 0){ 
    return sum === 0;
    }

    var arrBeginNum=arr[0];  

    // for every recursion take away one number(the first one in this case).
    arr = arr.slice(1);

    // first check if numbers sum up to largest num if not, check if removing numbers adds up to largest num.
    return recursionCheck(arr, sum) || recursionCheck(arr, sum - arrBeginNum);
  }

 // recursion needs to be called for it to start.
return recursionCheck(array, largestNum);
   }

// TESTS
console.log("-----");
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([1,2,3,5,4])); ==> true
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([21,10,12,9,2])); ==> true
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([4,6,23,10,1,3])); ===> true
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([5,7,16,1,2])); ===> false
console.log(ArrayAdditionI([3,5,-1,8,12])); ===> true
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort Array using

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b })
```

Comment: So you can write a function inside of methods to further manipulate what they already do?

Comment: Yes sort method do have function as parameter. Default sort() sorts string while this one sorts number. In short it indicates that I want to sort string or number.

Comment: Hey Parth thank you. Yes I understand that. Wait are you saying not all methods can take functions as parameters? Can you offer an example? Or is it possible to manipulate any method(with functions as parameters)? I wonder if there's some article about this...

Comment: btw I know about callbacks and Higher Order functions but this seems different since it's in a method...Even though I know methods are also functions...So I guess what I'm asking is how do I know when I can input functions as parameters(for methods) and is it possible for all methods?

Comment: This may help you to better understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537602/any-way-to-extend-javascripts-array-sort-method-to-accept-another-parameter

Comment: I just found this, particularly for the sort method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thank you! And last thing I just want to ask to make sure. Does this sort from smallest to largest? or largest to smallest? so a-b(largest to smallest), b-a(smallest to largest)? Thanks!!

Comment: No. a-b (smallest to largest) and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your input. You're awesome.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the complete solution yet, but here are the JavaScript-Problems:

`largestNum` was an array in you algorithm
`.sort()` was not working

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr){
    var largestNum = Math.max.apply(0, arr); // Gets the last number, which would be the largest.
    arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})
    arr.pop(); // Takes out the largest number for adding later.
    var result=0;
```

Also use `if(result !== largestNum) {`, Division is expensive and might have unexpected results with floating-point numbers.

Thats it for your JavaScript. But I am pretty sure the Algorithm is wrong - but I think this is up to you

Note that the example `[4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] => 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23` is not just adding up the lowest to the biggest value to try and match it.

Comment: you can skip the `1`, because it is possible to sum some items to the largest number.

Comment: Thank you! Is my way of getting the largest number not sufficient? If so, can you help me understand why so I know for next time? "var largestNum=newArr.slice(-1);"

Comment: "var largestNum=newArr.slice(-1);" is retourning an array wit the last element. You would need to do this: "var largestNum=newArr.slice(-1)[0];" ☺

Comment: Thanks CodeiSir. I've never seen slice being used that way. I looked up info on it but instead found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544452/remove-last-item-from-array

Comment: which states and explains slice(0, -1).

Answer (score 1):

A possible example of a solution for the problem.

> How this works:
>
> - First sort all items descending
> - Shift the first element to `largest`
> - Call the recursive function `y` with the reduced array, the largest value and a variable which holds an empty array for the successfully added items.
>
> The recursive function works basically in two parts
>
> 1. Test if the remaining sum is zero, if so the result is achieved and  return `true`, which finished the function.
> 2. If not iterate through the array and
>
>    - Make a copy from the array
>    - Get the value from the position with `splice`
>    - Test, if the value is smaller or equal the remaining sum and the result of the call of `y` with the shorted array, sum minus value and a new array with the used items and the acual item.
>    - If true return true and finish the function.
> 3. If not finished before return `false`.

```js
function x(array) {

    function y(a, s, result) {
        var aa, i, v;
        if (s === 0) {
            document.write('<pre>result: ' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
            return true;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            aa = a.slice();
            v = aa.splice(i, 1)[0];
            if (v <= s && y(aa, s - v, result.concat(v))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    var largest,
        r = [];
    array.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; });
    largest = array.shift();
    document.write('largest value: ' + largest + '<br>');
    return y(array, largest, r);
}

document.write(x([4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]) + '<hr>');
document.write(x([5, 7, 16, 1, 2]) + '<hr>');
document.write(x([3, 5, -1, 8, 12]));
```

Comment: Thank you Nina for taking the time to create a solution and writing out the steps, but I wasn't looking for a new solution. I want to figure out how I can fix what I already have. Particularly Bamar's suggestion of skipping over the problems. This is what I am trying to figure out now.

Comment: the problem, you have is, you loop only once over the items and try to get a result which at least requires to loop over the rest from the array again and again until a solution is found. beside that, your try to compare `result/largestNum !== 1` is not constructive, because you do not look up for difference but for quotient.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mar
Here is a version in Kotlin if someone needs

```
private fun returnResult(arr: Array<Int>): Boolean {
    arr.sort()
    val largestNumber = arr.last()
    val arrWithoutLargest = arr.dropLast(1).toTypedArray()
    return recursionCheck(arrWithoutLargest, largestNumber)
}

private fun recursionCheck(arr: Array<Int>, sum:Int): Boolean {
    if (arr.isEmpty()) return sum == 0

    val arrBeginNum = arr[0]

    val arr2 = arr.drop(1).toTypedArray()

    return recursionCheck(arr2, sum) || recursionCheck(arr2, sum - arrBeginNum)
}
```