# Get a single compare function to order both ASC and DESC using Array.sort()?

Tags: javascript

I need to order an **array of objects** by the property `price`.

Right now I have the following, which works as intended:

```
function orderByPriceASC(a,b) {
    return(
      a.price < b.price ? -1
      : a.price > b.price ? 1
        : 0
    );
  }

  function orderByPriceDESC(a,b) {
    return(
      a.price < b.price ? 1
      : a.price > b.price ? -1
        : 0
    );
  }

  function sortByPrice(order) {
    setProductList((prevState) => {
      const aux = Array.from(prevState);
      order === 'asc' ? aux.sort(orderByPriceASC) : aux.sort(orderByPriceDESC);
      return aux;
    });
  }
```

But can is there a way that I can structure this so I can get a single compare function that works for both ASC and DESC order?

Something like:

```
function orderByPrice(a,b,order) {
    return(
      a.price < b.price ?
        order === 'asc' ? -1 : 1
      : a.price > b.price ? 1
        order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1
        : 0
    );
  }
```

The problem is that I would have to send that extra parameter down to the `Array.sort` method which I don't think it's possible. Maybe with some wrapper function.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537602/any-way-to-extend-javascripts-array-sort-method-to-accept-another-parameter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `multiplier` and set it to `1` or `-1` based on the `order` variable. Then multiply it to the existing expression inside `compareFunction` (Here I'm assuming `price` is of type `number`)

```js
let arr = [{ price: 2 },{ price: 1 },{ price: 3 }]

function sort(array, order) {
  const multiplier = order === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
  return array.sort((a, b) => multiplier * (a.price - b.price))
}

console.log(sort(arr, "asc"))
console.log(sort(arr, "desc"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function and pass it to sort by binding it and sending a custom param like

```js
let arr = [{price: 1},{price: 11},{price: 7},{price: 1},{price: 9},{price: 5},]
function orderByPrice(order, a,b) {

        if(a.price < b.price) {
            if(order === 'asc') {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        } else if(a.price > b.price){
            if(order === 'asc') {
                return 1;
            }
            return -1
        }
        return 0;
      }
    
console.log(arr.sort(orderByPrice.bind(this, 'asc')))
console.log(arr.sort(orderByPrice.bind(this, 'desc')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
function flip(f) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return f(b, a);
    };
}

function orderByPriceASC(a,b) {
    return (
        a.price < b.price ? -1 :
        a.price > b.price ? 1 :
        0
    );
}

function sortByPrice(order) {
    setProductList((prevState) => {
        const aux = Array.from(prevState);
        aux.sort(order === 'asc' ? orderByPriceASC : flip(orderByPriceASC));
        return aux;
    });
}
```

This way you don't need a separate `orderByPriceDESC` function and you don't have to add any extra parameters either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the function return a function that accepts the direction as an argument, which is then passed into the inner function. I'm not a fan of flags in dynamically typed languages, but it would be something like this:

```
function orderByPrice(direction) { // either 'ASC' or 'DESC
  return function (a, b) {
    if (direction === 'DESC') {
      const temp = a;
      a = b
      b = temp;
    }
    return (
      a.price < b.price ? -1
        : a.price > b.price ? 1
          : 0
    );
  }
}
```

Then implementation would be

```
  function sortByPrice(direction) {
    setProductList((prevState) => {
      return Array.from(prevState).sort(orderByPrice(direction));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
let arr = [{ price: 2 },{ price: 1 },{ price: 3 }]

let sortBy = (arr, prop, dir=null) => 
  arr.slice().sort((a,b) => (a[prop] - b[prop]) * (dir ? -1 : 1))

console.log(sortBy(arr, 'price'))
console.log(sortBy(arr, 'price', 'desc')) // <-- any truthy value for `desc`
```

You have to use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to clone the array since [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) does mutate the array and you want a `pure` function. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Return_value):

> The sorted array. Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy
>   is made.

In addition if you are using lodash there is a [_.orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy) function for that already which also allows sorting on multiple props etc:

```js
let arr = [{ price: 2 },{ price: 1 },{ price: 3 }]

console.log(_.orderBy(arr, 'price'))
console.log(_.orderBy(arr, 'price', 'desc'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```